Price set fields amount limit?
Struggling with price fields visibility of an event info page. At some point fields of type CheckBox just stop appearing, but a new field of another type ( Text / Numeric Quantity, Radio ) is being displayed just fine. So I wonder, if there is a limit on a price fields of a certain type per a price set?
